# Html formatting in vs code

Tags: html, reactjs, format

I'm looking for a formatter, in vscode or online that will take those lines of code:

```
<button class="button button1" type="button">Green</button>
<button type="button" class="button button1">Blue</button>
```

And will format the tags to have the props in order:

```
<button class="button button1" type="button">Green</button>
<button class="button button1" type="button">Blue</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this extension: **Sorting HTML and Jade attributes**

Open html file.

> Press F1 and run the command named Sorting of the tag attributes
> (attrs-sorter)

[Link to install](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-attrs-sorter)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the extension doesn't seem to work in react and with react tags. Do you have more ideas :)

Comment: The question title wrote "HTML formatting" thats why I only looked for html extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) From vscode marketplace, Adjust settings for formatting shortcut
Default Shortcut : **Windows Shift + Alt + F**